# Application deployment and update monitoring using background services

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, service

I'm trying to accomplish a decoupled deployment of a GUI application (WPF) and two separate background services: one that monitors for updates of that GUI application and another that serves as a messaging channel for components inside the GUI application.

My initial idea was to have the parent service launch the event bus service before it launches the GUI app, because the event bus service gets to dictate the lifetime of the GUI app; if the event bus fails, then the GUI app cannot function. The parent service then also independently launches the updater service which can signal to the parent service if the GUI app and/or the event bus service should be shut down for updates.

The parent service dictates the lifetime of all of the services, they should go down when the parent service goes down.

```
           [[PARENT SERVICE]]
                  │
      ┌───────────┼───────────────┐
      │           │               │
[APP UPDATER]  [GUI APP] --> [APP EVENT BUS]
                      depends on
```

At first glance, adding the updater service to the parent background service seems straightforward with the `AddHostedService` since it just functions on its own, however, I can't seem to find any explanations on how to attach a WPF app to a background service. All I've found so far are hacky, synchronous ways to launch a process with no real control over the application lifetime. I would also need to find a way to give the WPF app access to the events service, but that's a separate concern.

Since I've never worked with background services before, I'm having a lot of trouble finding best practises and recommended deployment strategies, is this feasible in .NET or should I try something different?

UPDATES:

1. All the services/applications should run on a single client computer.
2. I'm separating the service bus from the GUI app because it needs to be a robust and independent messaging channel that must not fail if the GUI app fails.
3. The *decoupled* deployment refers to the GUI app being separated from its updater, the service bust must absolutely have a say in the application's lifetime*

(*) As far as this is possible, I yet have to find a way to "attach" the WPF app as a hosted service or launch it as part of the service starting one way or another.

Comment: You can use some IPC (named pipe, etc.) for the communication between parent service and GUI app.

Comment: I would consider a service bus or just rabbitmq as a candidate before named pipes, personally.  Is this all on one computer? Please improve your question by clarifying why you want a service bus at all. Decoupling deployment - what?  I don't get what that is. If it's multiple clients then why not a conventional client server?

Comment: Oh.. And a service has no ui.  You're going to need a security hole somewhere to start up a ui exe from a service.  Service and ui should start independently. Or they're also not really decoupled so well.

Comment: @Andy I want to use a service bus to reliably convey commands/events between various software components inside the GUI app. The GUI app *should* depend on the service bus because if it fails then the app's communication will fail.

Comment: Why would you not just use messenger though? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger A full on service bus just to do pub within the one app seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @Andy I was mainly concerned that the GUI app could somehow affect the messaging functionality, but if you think that those odds are low enough then you're probably right that I'm overdoing things.

Comment: I would message between viewmodels using messenger. I'd probably have a timer run a task on a background thread every 10 mins or something to look for a new version of the app. What that should do depends on what you need. Just copy everything down and use that new version next run is one option.